# Hosting Microsoft.ServiceModel.WebSockets.WebSocketService

Tags: wcf, websocket, iis-8, self-hosting, wcf-hosting

I was reading this [article about WCF Websockets](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/341413/What-s-new-in-WCF-4-5-WebSocket-support-Part-2-of), and there is a nice example of a WebSocket service using Microsoft.ServiceModel.WebSockets.WebSocketService, that looks perfect for a thing I want to do, clean and simple.

First of all, I have found it in a NuGet package named [Microsoft.WebSockets](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.WebSockets/), but it is from 2012 and states:

> This preview package provides functionality for writing
>   WebSocket-enabled server applications on Windows 8 using ASP.NET and
>   WCF. Requires .NET 4.5 RC and Windows 8 RC.

So it seems a little bit out of date. Is it deprecated/abandoned or anything?

Also, I would like to use it to create a standalone Windows service that handles the connections from browsers, but I cannot find how to host it. The example shows how to do it in IIS, but I cannot find information at all about how to host it in a Console or Windows service application.

Any idea about how to use it?

Cheers.

Comment: I have posted answer to the similar topic: [WCF self-hosted WebSocket Service with Javascript client](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24239953/wcf-self-hosted-websocket-service-with-javascript-client/26527058) Hope it will help.

Answer (score 1):

I believe WebSockets are included in .NET 4.5 in the [System.Net.WebSockets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.websockets%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) namespace.

Hopefully this will point you in the right direction:

[Using WebSockets in .NET 4.5 Part 3 (WCF)](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/619343/Using-WebSocket-in-NET-4-5-Part-3)